# Error mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002)

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, xampp, macos

Hola estoy programando en php e intento conectarme a una base de datos ya creada, con nombre `pruebas`, estoy utilizando XAMPP en una notebook mac. El problema ocurre cuando intento conectarme y me aparece el error `mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002)`. He intentado varias maneras diferentes, usando el puerto `3000`, `8080` y `8443`, además usando host con nombre `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` y también `192.168.64.2` y nada parece funcionar, he estado buscando soluciones al error en varios lugares sin éxito. Adjunto además capturas de pantalla de XAMPP, mi archivo php y mi BBDD en phpmyadmin.
 
[image: mi BBDD en phpmyadmin][image: XAMPP][image: XAMPP][image: XAMPP][image: Salida en navegador].

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $db_direccion="127.0.0.1";
        $db_usuario="root";
        $db_pass="";
        $db_nombre="prueba";
        $db_port = 3000;

        $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_direccion, $db_usuario, $db_pass, $db_nombre, $db_port);


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu MySQL a través de que puerto escucha?

Comment: acabo de hacer una query en phpmyadmin para buscar el puerto que esta usando y me muestra port 0, probablemente aca debe estar mi error

Answer (score 0):

acabo de hacer una query en phpmyadmin para buscar el puerto que esta usando y me muestra port 0, probablemente aca debe estar mi error [image: puerto]